# AngularJS and Animations

Tags: javascript, angularjs, css, animation

[ngAnimate](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ngAnimate) seems to be the foundation for triggering animations.  However, it does not contain any animations.

As I search around the web I see 2 different approaches; JavaScript based animations and CSS3 animations.  I understand the pluses and minuses to each, briefly here:

JavaScript:

- Supports older browser but can be choppy
- Easier to 'tie animations together'

CSS:

- Smoother
- Doesn't support old browsers
- The standard, id say?

So as I look around the web I see both implementations like:

- [angular-velocity](https://github.com/cgwyllie/angular-velocity)
- [ngAnimate](http://augus.github.io/ngAnimate/)
- [ngFx](https://github.com/Hendrixer/ngFx)
- [angular-motion](https://github.com/mgcrea/angular-motion)
- [animation.css](http://daneden.github.io/animate.css/) not angular based but easy to tie together.

Whats the 'standard' approach?  How are people using this in their complex angularjs application?  do you have any suggestions for other tools?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After lots of research, I ended up using css only animations with angular-animate module.

Here is a great article that overviews how to use it: http://www.yearofmoo.com/2013/08/remastered-animation-in-angularjs-1-2.html

If you look at the majority of css based transitions on the web they all have JS adding/removing classes.  Angular animate handles all this for you based on statements you are already using, just hook your code in.